# Naming for a software version with remote DB but s/w on user's computer

Tags: product, naming

I own a small software company that makes installed Windows software for small to mid-sized churches and charities.

We have several named versions of our software:

- Standalone, that has both the Windows application and its DB on the user's computer.
- Local Network, that has the DB on one computer in a local network, and the Windows application on each user's computer, accessing that single DB over the local network. (That version is split into the Local Network Server version, which is the one for the computer that has the DB on it, and the Local Network Client version, for the rest of the computers running the app on their computers.)
- Web Network, that has the DB on our server, and the Windows application securely accessing it on each user's computer over the Internet.

A lot of our users are volunteers who are not sophisticated at all in terms of computer knowledge.

We have realized that "Web Network" was a bad choice of name, because we keep having users misunderstand what that version is, thinking it's a true web application / SaaS, which obviously it isn't. This is despite lots of explanation about that on our website and in our Help file.

So we are looking for a new name for that version, that must **not** imply that the software itself is in any way web or cloud-based. So we want to stay away from anything that includes the words "web", "cloud", "Internet" or obvious synonyms.

A couple of options we are considering are "Hosted Database Version" and "Remote Database Version". I'm not perfectly happy with either:

- for "Hosted", many of our less sophisticated users will have no idea what that means, and (b) the more sophisticated users may still confuse it with "hosted software" which usually means SaaS, i.e. a true web app.
- "Remote" has its own problems, including potentially being confused with the Local Network Client Version.
- I rejected "Server Database Version", which I think is actually quite clear, because people could confuse it with our existing "Local Network Server Version" because of the shared word "Server".

Does anyone have any better ideas? (And please don't reply and tell us this is a bad design - we already have hundreds of users using the existing Web Network Version and do not plan to eliminate that option!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about

- Outsourced Version
- Thin Client Version
- Software-Only Version

?

Comment: Thanks, Michael, interesting ideas. I think the first two may be two techie for much our user base (or at least, mean nothing to them). And our Local Network Client Version is also a software-only version, so we need to have something less confusable with that.